# Do wald and score-tests work when we have nuisance parameters?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, wald-test

Do wald and score-tests work when we have nuisance parameters?

> In statistics, a nuisance parameter is any parameter which is unspecified ${ }^{[1]}$ but which must be accounted for in the hypothesis testing of the parameters which are of interest. The classic example of a nuisance parameter comes from the specific example of a distribution in the Location-scale family called the Normal distribution. For a normal distribution, the variance, $\sigma^{2}$ is often not specified or known, but one desires to hypothesis test on the mean. Another example might be linear regression with unknown variance in the exploratory variable. The independent variable's variance is a nuisance parameter that must be accounted for to derive an accurate interval estimate of the slope, calculate p-values, hypothesis test on the slope's value. See regression dilution.
> Nuisance parameters are often scale-parameters from the Location-scale family, but not always; for example in errorsin-variables models, the unknown true location of each observation is a nuisance parameter. A parameter may also cease to be a "nuisance" if it becomes the object of study, is estimated from data, or known--wikipedia.org

Comment: Yes, easily. One simply uses the information matrix for the test parameters adjusted for the nuisance parameters, i.e., ${\cal I}_{2.1}={\cal I}_{11}-{\cal I}_{12}{\cal I}_{22}^{-1}{\cal I}_{21}$ where ${\cal I}_{11}$ is the information matrix for the test parameters and ${\cal I}_{22}$ is the information matrix for the nuisance parameters. The nuisance parameters are set at their MLE.

Comment: @Gordon Symyth What is $\mathcal{I}_{12}$?

Comment: As a special case, if the two random variables are independent, the information yielded by the two random variables is the sum of the information from each random variable separately:
$$
\mathcal{I}_{X, Y}(\theta)=\mathcal{I}_{X}(\theta)+\mathcal{I}_{Y}(\theta)
$$

Comment: $$
\mathcal{I}_{X, Y}(\theta)=\mathcal{I}_{X}(\theta)+\mathcal{I}_{Y \mid X}(\theta),
$$
where $\mathcal{I}_{Y \mid X}(\theta)=\mathrm{E}_{X}\left[\mathcal{I}_{Y \mid X=x}(\theta)\right]$ and $\mathcal{I}_{Y \mid X=x}(\theta)$ is the Fisher information of $Y$ relative to $\theta$ calculated with respect to the conditional density of $Y$ given a specific value $X=x$.

Comment: Is that way you mean? credits-wikipedia.org

Comment: No, I mean nothing like that at all. The problem has two parameters, not two random variables. The equation you give have no relevance to Wald or score tests.

Comment: ${\cal I}_{12}$ is the upper right-hand quadrant of the joint information matrix. The joint information matrix for the test parameter $\theta_1$ and the nuisance parameter $\theta_2$ is made up of the four submatrices ${\cal I}_{11}$, ${\cal I}_{12}$, ${\cal I}_{21}$ and ${\cal I}_{22}$. See for example  Smyth, G.K. Partitioned algorithms for maximum likelihood and other non-linear estimation. Stat Comput 6, 201–216 (1996). https://doi.org/10.1007/BF00140865.

Comment: WHat's a joint information matrix? Is it whenever you have more than one parameter? If you don't have nuisance parameters, then di you still have a joint information matrix? In Sage code, it always computed a information matrix part of it wasn't what I was look for, so I realize the info matrix is bigger than what I thought. @GordonSmyth